# Allow events to be posted in EvenQueue between postEvent calls in Swing

Tags: java, swing, events

I am trying to emulate click events in Swing using following code:

```
event = new MouseEvent(target, MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ...)
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(event);
event = new MouseEvent(target, MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, ...)
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(event);
event = new MouseEvent(target, MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, ...)
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(event);
```

This works fine for most components, but the problem is if component is generating it's own events, for example if when component receives MOUSE_PRESSED it generates some events and submits them with dispatchEvent(newEvent); With normal click event order would be:

```
MOUSE_PRESSED
newEvent
MOUSE_RELEASED
MOUSE_CLICKED
```

But because of my code order is:

```
MOUSE_PRESSED    
MOUSE_RELEASED
MOUSE_CLICKED
newEvent
```

And it breaks application logic. I can easily fix it by adding Thread.sleep() calls between my postEvent() calls, but I don't want to do it since this method is called a lot and I don't want it to be slow, especially since current code works in 95% of cases.

How would I emulate event sequence allowing new events to be created between them? I don't have access to component code, so I can only modify my emulation method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could push your own event queue which would give you total control of events. For example:

```
    class SchedulingEventQueue extends EventQueue
    {
      // Use Map< AWTEvent, List< AWTEvent > > to support multiple events
      private final Map< AWTEvent, AWTEvent > eventSchedule = new HashMap< AWTEvent, AWTEvent >();

      public void scheduleEvent( final AWTEvent event, final AWTEvent dependentEvent )
      {
        eventSchedule.put( dependentEvent, event );
      }

      @Override
      protected void dispatchEvent( final AWTEvent event )
      {
        try
        {
          super.dispatchEvent( event );
        }
        finally
        {
          // Dispatch any dependent event
          AWTEvent scheduledEvent = eventSchedule.remove( event );
          if( scheduledEvent != null )
          {
            postEvent( scheduledEvent );
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Now the code to post the events becomes:
    {
      SchedulingEventQueue eventQueue = new SchedulingEventQueue();

      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().push( eventQueue );

      MouseEvent pressEvent = new MouseEvent(target, MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ...)
      MouseEvent releaseEvent = new MouseEvent(target, MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, ...)
      MouseEvent clickEvent = new MouseEvent(target, MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, ...)

      eventQueue.scheduleEvent( clickEvent, releaseEvent );
      eventQueue.scheduleEvent( releaseEvent, pressEvent );
      eventQueue.postEvent( pressEvent );
    }
```

You just chain the events together so that they don't get posted until the previous event has been dispatched allowing any intermediate events created by a component to be posted during dispatch before your next event is posted. I haven't tried this but it should work.

Comment: Alternatively you could implement a postEvents( List< AWTEvent > events ) with the scheduling handled internally to prevent the calling code having to get the scheduleEvent() and postEvent() calls in the correct order. You could just iterate over the list in reverse order, scheduling each one, then post the first event.

Comment: This works perfectly, few questions: 1) getSystemEventQueue().push( eventQueue ), should I call it each time I emulate mouse click, or push it once and reuse each time? I don't see any method to remove my eventQueue from system when I don't need it anymore 2) I am trying to modify it to check when it finishes processing events, http://pastebin.com/h6zFMfH3 , works fine until events creates a modal dialog, which blocks dispatchEvent, how do I check that current event is blocked? Thanks again!

Comment: You only need to push the event queue once and then just reuse the single SchedulingEventQueue instance for each set of events.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [e.consume()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369612/714968) for event from mouse / keyboard events, and/or replace/generate own even(s) to the `EventQueue`